# Packing problem over discrete space

Tags: co.combinatorics, sphere-packing

Let $q$ be an positive integer and $F = \{0,1,\dots,q-1\}$, we define Hamming distance in $F^n$ between $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n), y = (y_1, \dots, y_n) \in F^n$ is the number of indices $i$ such that $x_i \neq y_i$.

**Question.** For $R, D > 0$. What is maximum number of non-overlap circles of radius $D$ can be packed in to a circle of radius $R$?

For a fixed point $x \in F^n$. The number of point in $C(x,R)$ - circle of radius $R$ with center $x$ - is
$$V(n,R) = \sum_{i = 0}^R \binom{n}{i} (q-1)^i.$$
Therefore, we have a trivial upper bound for this question is $\frac{V(n,R)}{V(n,D)}$. Any better bound we can have?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
The question stated packing in an arbitrary sphere of radius $R,$ which can be less than $n.$ The code examples below being cyclic have a homegeneity property on coordinates. They also support designs and orthogonal arrays. This may be a fruitful direction to investigate the packing radius of the projections of these codes onto $R$ coordinates and look at the worst case packing radius.

*Original Answer:*

This is a question about coding theory.

If the upper bound you mention is attained, we have what is called a *perfect code*; your  bound is known as the Hamming bound in coding theory. I will use $t$ for the packing radius, $D$ is used for the Hamming distance normally.

For $t=1,$ the whole space made up of all words $F^n$ is a trivial perfect code.

Other trivial perfect codes are the repetition code of odd length $n$ when $q=2,$ namely
$$
\{ (0,0,\ldots,0),(1,1,\ldots,1)\}
$$
which has $t=n.$ It has been proved that the only other perfect codes that exist when $q=p^m,$ i.e., a power of a prime are the Hamming code $(q=2,n=2^m-1,t=1),$ and the binary $(q=2,n=23,t=3)$ and ternary $(q=3,n=11,t=2),$ Golay codes.

No other perfect codes are known.

When a perfect code doesn't exist there are some lower bounds on $t,$ including the Gilbert-Varshamov bound which guarantees the existence of a code with a given $t,$ once $q,n$ are specified. There are other results as well, too complicated to summarize here. The big textbook at graduate level is Conway and Sloane's Sphere Packings book.

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-6568-7

Depending on your background, I suggest starting with Jon Hall's coding theory text which is available online for a gentler introduction to the topic of coding theory:

https://users.math.msu.edu/users/halljo/classes/codenotes/coding-notes.html

This chapter covers some bounds:

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse533/06au/lecnotes/lecture5.pdf

See also below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golay_code

Comment: The question actually is more general, because the OP asks about packing Hamming balls with radius $D$ into a fixed Hamming ball of radius $R$. So your answer is the special case $R=n$. Nevertheless, the references in the answer is a good source to learn about packing bounds.